# Eclipse:IWAV0171E Could not create a socket connection to remote vm

Tags: eclipse-rcp, firewall, jvm-crash

I had my Eclipse nicely setup for writing simple Java desktop applications untill today when I tried to open a class in Visual Editor I`m getting the error:

```
---------------------------
Error:
---------------------------
IWAV0138E Remote VM terminated too soon. See .log file for trace of output.  
For VM "Project (MyProj)-VM for MyProj".
```

In details the information is :

```
An internal error occurred during: "Create Remote VM for Visual Editor for Java".
IWAV0171E Could not create a socket connection to remote vm. 
This is often due to your firewall blocking access from your java 
to do local access.
```

---

Now I looked around and found that `javaw.exe` cannot make a local connection and the firewall is blocking , so I turned off the firewall, both Windows and Kaspersky, but that didnt make any difference.

Further I tried modifying the host file in `win/system32/drivers/etc`, which already had `127.0.0.1` linked to `localhost`, but i added another line with real network ip and computer name and that didn't work too.

I tried running Eclipse that I have embedded in Oracle Weblogic , and it works, so I am guessing it is only with the JDK I`m using? anybody had this problem?

regards,
Imran

Comment: What exact jvm are you using to launch Eclipse and/or to run your program?

Comment: C:\java -version java version "1.6.0_24" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07) Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)

this is the version, I update it a few days ago, didnt have any issues. But I do recall updating IE8 from IE7, could that have something to do with it?